# How does Lucene work

Tags: lucene

I would like to find out how lucene search works so fast. I can't find any useful docs on the web. If you have anything (short of lucene source code) to read, let me know.

A text search query using mysql5 text search with index takes about 18 minutes in my case. A lucene search for the same query takes less than a second.

Comment: Can I request this question to be converted as a community wiki ? Lucene sounds like a platform now.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Lucene is an inverted full-text index. This means that it takes all the documents, splits them into words, and then builds an index *for each word*. Since the index is an exact string-match, unordered, it can be extremely fast. Hypothetically, an SQL unordered index on a `varchar` field could be just as fast, and in fact I think you'll find the big databases can do a simple string-equality query very quickly in that case.

Lucene does not have to optimize for transaction processing. When you add a document, it need not ensure that queries see it *instantly*. And it need not optimize for updates to existing documents.

However, at the end of the day, if you really want to know, you need to read the source. Both things you reference are open source, after all.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the thing that sets text search engines apart is how they handle multi-word searches and joining the results of searches to multiple indexes in real time. I would not suggest consulting Lucene source for this. It would probably be better to read a little about text search theory, @alienCoder's answer helped me.

Comment: @bmargulies, If the indexing is "per word", then why does the stackoverflow user search http://stackoverflow.com/users allow substring matches?

Comment: This is not the place for whole-book answers. There are any number of elaborations on  the basic concept in there.

Comment: What do you mean "an index for each word"...if I start typing "abc", how is it going to find "abc" in the document?

Comment: An index (B-tree) from word to document can search for documents by words in the document because the table of such an index is (word, document) where the index is on the word column. Consider a query like: "Find documents with words 'police','crime','statistics'" in them. By searching the word index, you can do three log(N) searches to get O(N) documents with one of those words in them. Then you can do two O(N) loops to build a set containing documents that have all three words. Although this is theoretically a O(N) operation, most documents don't have all three words so its O(n) where n < N.

Answer (score 41):

Lucene creates a big index. The index contains word id, number of docs where the word is present, and the position of the word in those documents. So when you give a single word query it just searches the index (O(1) time complexity). Then the result is ranked using different algorithms. For multi-word query just take the intersection of the set of files where the words are present.
Thus Lucene is very very fast.

For more info read this article by Google developers- http://infolab.stanford.edu/~backrub/google.html

Comment: Skimmed over that paper, it was pretty helpful. Specifically "4.5 Searching" had the answer I was looking for. Specifically, it sounds like an O(1) hash search is used for individual words, but then an O(n) scan is used to join the results with a 40,000 document limit. I assume a map-reduce algorithm is used to split this work up so that the user gets instantaneous results.

Comment: One popular algorithm is pigeon rank algorithm. Although I don't know much about it.

Comment: That paper is amusing: "In this paper, we present Google, a prototype...". I guess Google wasn't always a mega-corporation.

Comment: don't know Lucene, but one question: Ranking happens at each search? Or does it maintains the documents pre-ranked? If it maintain the documents as per rank in advance how does it maintain for multiple words query?

Comment: The link is broken now. @alienCoder

Answer (score 21):

In a word: indexing.

Lucene creates an index of your document that allows it to search much more quickly.

It's the same difference between a list O(N) data structure and a hash table O(1) data structure.  The list has to walk through the entire collection to find what you want.  The hash table has an index that lets it figure out exactly where the desired item is and simply fetch it.

Update:

I'm not certain what you mean by "Lucene index searches are a lot faster than mysql index searches."

My guess is that you're using MySQL "WHERE document LIKE '%phrase%'" to search for a document.  If that's true, then MySQL has to do a table scan on every row, which will be O(N).

Lucene gets to parse the document into tokens, group them into n-grams at your direction, and calculate indexes for each one of those.  It's O(1) to find a word in an indexed Lucene document.

Comment: Yes I understand the indexing part, but again, lucene index searches are a lot faster than mysql index searches. How does that happen

Answer (score 14):

Lucene works with **[Term frequency and Inverse document frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf)**. It creates an index mapping each word with the document and it's frequency count which is nothing but inverse index on the document.

> **Example** :
>
> File 1 : Random Access Memory is the main memory.
>
> File 2 : Hard disks are secondary memory.

Lucene creates a reverse index something like

File 1 :

**Term : Random**

Frequency : 1

Position : 0

**Term : Memory**

Frequency : 2

Position : 3

Position : 6

So it is able to search and retrieve the searched content quickly. When there is too many matches for the search query it outputs the result based on the weight. Consider the search query **"Main Memory"** it searches for all 4 words individually and the result would be like,

**Main**

File 1 : Frequency - 1

**Memory**

File 1 : Frequency - 2

File 2 : Frequency - 1

The result would be **File1** followed by **File2**. To stop getting carried away by weights on most common words like 'and', 'or', 'the' it considers the inverse document frequency (ie' it decreases the weight of the word which is most popular among the document set).